# python - login a page and get cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

First, thanks for taking the time to read this and maybe trying to help me.

I am trying to make a script to easily login in a site. I wanted to get the login cookies too, so maybe I could reuse them later. I made the script and it logs me in correctly. But I can not get the cookies. When I try to print them, I see just this:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

Obviously this can't help me, I think. So now I would be interested in knowing how to get the real cookie data. Thanks a lot to whoever can hep me reaching that.

My code:

```
import requests
import cfscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
header = {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"}
s = requests.session()
scraper=cfscrape.create_scraper(sess=s) #i use cfscrape because the page uses cloudflare anti ddos page
        scraper.get("https://www.bstn.com/einloggen", headers=header)
        myacc={"login[email]": "my@mail.com", #obviously change
        "login[password]": "password123"}
        entry=scraper.post("https://www.bstn.com/einloggen", headers=header, data=myacc)
        soup=bs(entry.text, 'lxml')
        accnm=soup.find('meta',{'property':'og:title'})['content']
        print("Logged in as: " + accnm)
        aaaa=scraper.get("https://www.bstn.com/kundenkonto", headers=header)
        print(aaaa.cookies)
```

If I print the ccokies, I just get the `<RequestsCookiesJar[]>` like described earlier... It would be really nice if anyone could help me getting the "real" cookies

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get your login cookie that you ought to use the response which after posting, because you are doing login action! Server will send back session cookies if you input correct email&password. And why you got empty cookies in `aaaa` is website didn't want to set or change your cookies.

```
entry = scraper.post("https://www.bstn.com/einloggen", allow_redirects=False, headers=header, data=myacc)
print(entry.cookies)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your helpful answer. I tried exactly this, unfortunately I still get an empty cookie. Does that have any specific meanings or something? Thanks

Comment: im sry, i answer it before i got account on website. My answer is right actually, but why it show nothing because redirect!. After login successfully, you will be redirected to another page, so your response was changed. When you set `allow_redirects = False` everything was fine.